# How to write negation of statements?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

How to write negation of following statements in words?

```
1. Any integer is either positive or negative.
2. There is a child who is loved by everyone.
3. The connector is loose or the machine is unplugged.
4. No politician cheat voters.
```

And how to write negation of following statement in symbols?

```
5. (∀x)(∃y)(x^2 <y)
```

For 3rd one my answer is "The connector is not loose and the machine is not unplugged" and for 4th one my answer is "politician cheat voters". I am not sure...Are they correct?

Comment: Yes I have tried. But not sure. For 3rd one my answer is "The connector is not loose and the machine is not unplugged".

Comment: For 4th one my answer is "Politician cheat voters". I cannot imagine how to solve other ones. I do not know how to answer questions such as 5. How to negate when there are more than one quantifiers?

Comment: Your solution for 3. looks good. What about the others?

Comment: To get the negation for your 4 statements, you should translate it to formulas, compute the negation and reformulate it as a sentence. To negate a logical symbol, think that it is a dual operation : double negation is the same as identity (at least in classical logic), and the negation of (P(x) AND P(y)) is (not P(x) OR not P(y)), so it turns AND to OR (and vice-versa), and FORALL to IT EXISTS. Can you try to negate your formula $(\forall x)(\exists y)(x^2 < y)$ now ?

Comment: For 4: Try to reformulate the statement like "For all Politicans p : p does not cheat his voters"

Comment: @YannHamdaoui - How do u say that FORALL is converted to IT EXISTS when negating? Is there a rule for it?

Comment: @naslundx can u show your answers with clarifications please?

Comment: Yes it is a general rule, and it is actually quite intuitive. For example, let's take the proposition "all of my friends are males", that we can write $\forall friend, male(friend)$ if male is the property of being a male. Then, in your opinion, what is the negation of this formula ? For this formula to be false, you just need that at least one of your friends is not a male. That is : "I have a friend, who is not a male". So, in propositional calculus, you have indeed $\neg(\forall friend, male(friend))$ = $\exists friend, \neg(male(friend))$ and here $\exists friend, (female(friend))$.

Comment: @user127.0.0.1 can u please explain me why this question was put on hold as off-topic? I'm new to this forum. This is a question that I was unnable to solve and that is why I put it here.

Comment: @YannHamdaoui Thanks for ur support. (∃x)(∀y)¬(X^2<y)  Is this correct for question 5 according to ur explanation.?

Comment: @SamithaChathuranga yes it is ! You can even totally get rid of the negation here since $\neg (X^2 < y)$ is $X^2 \geq y$ but your answer is still correct

Comment: @Yann I got it..!! Thanks bro.. And can u please explain the 2nd one with using predicates. I am interested to know how to solve such a question step by step writing predicates with appropriate symbols. The answer for it is given by Irvon below as "There is no child who is loved by everyone."

Comment: Yes. Actually I think the language can be confusing, I guess you wonder why there is a "There is no" when we explained you that a there is becomes a forall. If you translate the sentence to a formula, you have $\exists child, P(child)$ where $P(child)=$"child is loved by everyone". Actually, using natural language, Irvon is right but he cheated a bit : he kept the form $\neg (\ldots...)$. If your sentence is $\exists child, child is loved by everyone$, there he just translated in english $\neg (\exists child,child$ is loved by everyone$)$, which seems natural to us.

Comment: If you want to use the rule above, it will lead to $\neg (\exists child, P(child)) = \forall child, \neg P(child) = \forall child, child$ is $NOT$ loved by everyone. If, for any child, this child can't be loved by everyone : it is indeed equivalent to say that there is no child that can be loved by everyone. This example is vicious, because it mixes the expressiveness of natural language and the one of propositionnal calculus. Here you didn't really need the propositional calculs for 2), but for more complex sentences, it is definitely the better (if not the only) way to find the negation.

Comment: @Yann Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me give this a go. The first one is trickiest because of the "either-or" construction.

1. There is an integer that is both positive and negative, or neither positive nor negative.
2. (a) There is no child who is loved by everyone. (b) For each child, there is someone who does not love the child.
3. The connector is not loose and the machine is not unplugged. (You already said it.)
4. There is a politician who cheats voters.
5. $(\exists x)(\forall y)(x^2 \geq y)$

Indeed, it is a rule that $(\neg \forall x)(\phi) = (\exists x)(\neg \phi)$ where $\phi$ is a proposition. This should be intuitively clear: if $\phi$ holds for not all $x$, then there must be an $x$ such that $\phi$ does not hold. It is a good exercise to write your original statements in formal symbols and then negate them. For example:

1. $(\forall x \in \mathbb{Z})((x > 0 \wedge x \nless 0) \vee (x < 0 \wedge x \ngtr 0))$

This seems a bit silly, but your either-or construction forces me to write it like this. If the original statement were

"Any integer is positive or negative",

then I could have written

$(\forall x \in \mathbb{Z})(x > 0 \vee x <0),$

which is equivalent in this case because being positive and being negative are already mutually exclusive. The negation of 1. in formal symbols is

\begin{eqnarray*} \neg(\forall x \in \mathbb{Z})((x > 0 \wedge x \nless 0) \vee (x < 0 \wedge x \ngtr 0)) & = & \\
(\neg \forall x \in \mathbb{Z})((x > 0 \wedge x \nless 0) \vee (x < 0 \wedge x \ngtr 0)) & = & \\
(\exists x \in \mathbb{Z})\neg((x > 0 \wedge x \nless 0) \vee (x < 0 \wedge x \ngtr 0)) & = & \\
(\exists x \in \mathbb{Z})(\neg(x > 0 \wedge x \nless 0) \wedge \neg(x < 0 \wedge x \ngtr 0)) & = & \\
(\exists x \in \mathbb{Z})((\neg(x > 0) \vee \neg(x \nless 0)) \wedge (\neg(x < 0) \vee \neg(x \ngtr 0))) & = & \\
(\exists x \in \mathbb{Z})(x \ngtr 0 \vee x < 0) \wedge (x \nless 0 \vee x > 0)
\end{eqnarray*}

With one more step you can that this is the negation of statement 1. in words. Use the [rules of passage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rules_of_passage_%28logic%29).

Comment: And can u please explain the 2nd one with predicates. I am interested to know how to solve such a question by writing predicates with appropriate symbols.

Comment: "Either/or" means exactly the same as "or". If someone wants to say "but not both", they have to say that explicitly. The negation of (1) is just "there is an integer that is not positive and not negative"

Comment: @CarlMummert Thanks a lot.

Comment: @CarlMummert but the english meaning of either/or is that "not both" but "only one of them". So how could that differ in logic?

Comment: @Samitha Chathuranga - to work in math, everyone needs to come to an agreement about how to read things the same way. The established convention is that "either or" is read the same as "or". To convey "not both", the convention is that you must say that explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is not the case that any integer is either positive or negative.
2. It is not the case that there is a child who is loved by everyone.
3. It is not the case that the connector is loose or the machine is unplugged.
4. It is not the case that no politicians cheat voters.
5. $\lnot$[(∀x)(∃y)(x^2 < y)]

Answer (score 0):

To negate a collection of statements simultaneously, turn  each statement into symbolical form and then negate the whole on the basis of de Morgan's law. That is a very easy way to negate a collection of statements simultaneously.

Answer (score -1):

Write the negation of each statement

Some telephone can take photographs
All houses have two stories
Some cars are hybrids
All golf course are green
Some drivers are not safe